# Async Server Client Socket approach to Pong in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous, pong

i´ve finished a simple Pong in C# like a experimental work.
My plan to do that is how to work Networks messages for games with update in real time. High flow of messages to update the objects.

So my question is, whats the best approach to do this?
My game is really simple, i have 2 paddles, 1 ball, and my plan is to connect the two players to a Server and send messages from Client to Server and Server to Client to update the objects.
Is Async Server Client Socket the best solution? 
or i need to use another solution for this propose?

Thanks, suggests of all kind are very welcome.

Comment: Do you need authentication? Do you need to handle many players (or just a second player connecting)? There are too many options here without narrowing down what the units you want to interconnect are.

Comment: @Richard In order to do simple, i just want to connect 2 players, maybe when i can handle it i would like to work with more players.

Comment: The first choice is to have a separate server and client (so two exe's needed) or just have a client that can connect to another client. (Summary: you can use sockets, but the low level details should follow the higher level design choices.)